# virtualbox и зависание компьютера

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Добрый день!
Столкнулся с проблемой : не могу запустить виртуальную Win 7 x32. Версия VirtualBox 5.0.40_Ubuntu r115130
Работала VB нормально, никаких нареканий. Выключил виртуальную машину, закрыл VB - так я завершил работу с программой. Не могу точно сказать после чего она перестала работать. Сейчас включаю Oracle VM VirtualBox Менеджер, жму Запустить чтобы загрузить Windows и результат - полное зависание компьютера. Приходится делать hard reset.
Логи пусты(!).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как диагностировать и решить проблему.

Comment: Это произошло, скорее всего, после установки обновления для защиты от Meltdown

Comment: Такая же ситуация. Изначально машины не запускались из-за ошибки. После переустановок при запуске машины система просто зависает наглухо. Логи VirtualBox пустые. Ковырялся немного, но результат нулевой.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить версию Virtual Box до последней версии 5.2. Может исправили ситуацию

Comment: @LEQADA спасибо за подсказку, все работает. Дополнительно пришлось поставить расширение для VB -  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вольный перевод ответа https://askubuntu.com/a/994653

> Virtualbox 5.0.40 не работает с новым ядром 4.13.0-26, но VBox 5.2
>   работает нормально.
>
> Скачайте его с официальной страницы VirtualBox или добавьте следующую
>   строку в `/etc/apt/sources.list`:
>
> ```
> deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
> ```
>
> Если вы пользуетесь версией Ubuntu отличной от 16.04, то используйте
>   соответствующее название вместо `xenial`
>
> Добавьте публичный ключ Oracle:
>
> ```
> wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Обновите репозитории и установите virtualbox-5.2:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2
> ```
>
> На одном из моих машин VM отказывался запускаться. Помогло удаление
>   `virutalbox-dkms`:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
> ```
>
> После обновления у меня была проблема (см VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx
>   failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)) после запуска виртуальной машины. Эта
>   проблема была решена следующей командой:
>
> ```
> sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
> ```